# React Native Moment Error: Expected a component class, got [object Object]

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I read at least eight Stack Overflow posts about the error in the title, but I haven't yet resolved the issue since I capitalized everything in `<>`s and don't use HTML tags.  Using Moment documentation as a guide, I'm trying to display the current day of the week in the first `<Moment></Moment>` and a date like October 9th, 2017 in the second.  Below I pasted my App.js.  I used create-react-native app to get started.  What should I do instead?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Moment from 'react-moment';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Moment format="dddd"></Moment>
        <Moment format='MMMM Do YYYY'></Moment>
        <Text>Today at a Glance</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Does the component render when you remove the following lines?:

`<Moment format="dddd"></Moment>
 <Moment format='MMMM Do YYYY'></Moment>`

Comment: You are giving a format but not giving any date to format.

Comment: Yes 223seneca, when I commented out those lines the component renders. Also, Stoic philosophy rocks!

Comment: I also tried passing {new Date()} between the the Moment XMLs, bennygenel.  Nice name by the way

Comment: Also, I experimented with the code below and still got the error in the title of this page:

Comment: render() {
    let now = new Date();
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Moment format="dddd">{now}</Moment>
        <Moment format='MMMM Do YYYY'>{now}</Moment>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and I found this in doc:
`<Moment element={Text} >1976-04-19T12:59-0500</Moment>`

We need to to pass the element. The error message don't help, but doing this it works for me

doc link:
https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment#usage-with-react-native

Comment: Thank you rmovieira!  When I changed my rendering function to the below, the app rendered correctly:

Comment: render() {
      let now = new Date();

      return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
          <Moment element={Text} format="dddd">{now}</Moment>
          <Moment element={Text} format='MMMM Do YYYY'>{now</Moment>
          <Text>Today at a Glance</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }